# ask about jquery upload multiple image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, image-uploading, dropzone.js

I want to upload an image with a preview after I use jquery dropzone.

At first if only one image is uploaded using dropzone the image shows up and a unique name is givin using date+rndom number.

that's the first way,

the second way,
I want to add one image and give and unique name too,have to save it in the database too. But when the second image is being uploaded, it replaces the first image

Is there any way to do it

======================================================================

This is the the script to execute multiple upload images,
place on view: header.php. i made same function for other dropzone function in the header.php. just replace the div tag id and input tag in the view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  var name = Date.now();
  var key = Math.floor((Math.random() * 99999999999) + 1);
  var unique = name+'-'+key;

  $("div#eyeDropZone").dropzone({
       url:'http://localhost/work/uploadimage/multiple/'+unique,

       paramName:'foto', // param to upload image name to db
       uploadMultiple:false,
       maxFiles:2,

       acceptedFiles: '.jpg',
       maxFilesize:1,
       addRemoveLinks: 'no',
       dictFileTooBig: "File size ({{filesize}}MB). Max File Size: {{maxFilesize}}MB.",
       dictInvalidFileType: "JPG Only",


      init: function() {
        this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file) {
        this.removeAllFiles();
        this.addFile(file);

        });
        this.on("removedfile", function(file, xhr, formData) {
        $("#filename").val('');
         });
       },

      accept: function(file, done) {
        var filename = file.name;
        $("#filename").val(unik);
        done();
        }
  });
});
</script>
```

this is the controller, this code was developed by friend. he need my help to change a little,
at the first only upload image to folder first using jquery dropzone 
and delete the image from the folder then insert to database also save image to folder.

```
public function birthday_upload($unique='')
{
  error_reporting(0);
  $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div style="border: 1px solid: #999999; background-color: #ffff99;">', '</div>');

  $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
  $original_path                     = './birthday/original';
  $resized_path                      = './birthday/resized';
  $thumbs_path                       = './birthday/thumb';
  $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);

  unlink('./birthday/original/'.$uniks.'.jpg');
  unlink('./birthday/resized/'.$uniks.'.jpg');
  unlink('./birthday/thumb/'.$uniks.'.jpg');

  $config = array(
          'allowed_types'   => 'jpg|jpeg',
          'max_size'        => 1024,
          'upload_path'     => $original_path, //upload directory
          'file_name'       => $uniks,
          );

  $gambar['filename'] = $uniks;
  $this->load->library('upload', $config);
  $this->upload->do_upload('foto');
  $image_data = $this->upload->data(); //upload the image
  $image['foto'] = $image_data['file_name'];

  //your desired config for the resize() function
  $config = array(
          'source_image'     => $image_data['full_path'], //path to the uploaded image
          'new_image'        => $resized_path,
          'maintain_ratio'   => false,
          'width'            => 566,
          'height'           => 238
          );

  $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
  $this->image_lib->resize();

  // for the Thumbnail image
  $config = array(
          'source_image'         => $image_data['full_path'],
          'new_image'            => $thumbs_path,
          'maintain_ratio'       => true,
          'width'                => 100,
          'height'               => 100
          );

  //here is the second thumbnail, notice the call for the initialize() function again
  $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

  $this->birthday_m->simpan($gambar);

}
```

this is how insert the image

```
public function simpan($gambar)
{
  error_reporting(0);

  $name_fb              = mysql_real_escape_string($this->input->post('name'));
  $gender_fb            = mysql_real_escape_string($this->input->post('gender'));
  $tempat_lahir_fb  = mysql_real_escape_string($this->input->post('pob_child'));
  $child_birth_fb   = mysql_real_escape_string($this->input->post('birth_child'));
  $email_fb                 = mysql_real_escape_string($this->input->post('email'));
  $address_fb           = mysql_real_escape_string($this->input->post('address'));
  $nama_anak_fb         = mysql_real_escape_string($this->input->post('child_name'));
  $filename_fb          = mysql_real_escape_string($this->input->post('foto_name').'.jpg');
  // add to the line below to save image name to database
  $akta_fb                  = mysql_real_escape_string($this->input->post('akta_name').'.jpg');

  $data= array(
    'name_fbd'                  => $name_fb,
    'email_fbd'                 => $email_fb,
    'address_fbd'           => $address_fb,
    'nama_anak_fbd'         => $nama_anak_fb,
    'tempat_lahir_fbd'  => $tempat_lahir_fb,
    'child_birth_fbd'       => $child_birth_fb,
    'filename_fbd'          => $filename_fb,
    'filename_akta'         => $akta_fb,
    'gender_fbd'            => $gender_fb,
    'dateregister_fbd'  => $now,
    'voucher_fbd'           => $voucher,
    'handphone_fbd'         => $handphones,
    // 'dateupdate'     => ''
  );


  $this->db->insert('mydatabase',$data);
  {
    redirect(''.base_url().'birthdays/success/');
  }
}
```

this is the view,
i made other dropzone function for new dropzone area to upload the image,
it was success show image in dropzone area,but the first image was replace by the second image.
and filaname only show one below the dropzone area.

```
<div class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone">
  <div id="eyeDropZone" class="dropzone" ></div>
  <input multiple  name="foto_name" type="text" id="filename"  required readonly />

</div>
<div class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone">
  <div id="eyeDropZone" class="dropzone" ></div>
  <input multiple  name="akta_name" type="text" id="filenameakta"  required readonly/>
</div>
```

Comment: This is really a matter of handling on the beack-end. What code language are you using there? PHP or other? I do multiple uploads, but use the file's original name to prevent overwrite,

Comment: sorry for late. i use php codeigniter @Daniel

Comment: First of all it is a bad practice to have the name of the id's same. and why do you need two divs of dropzone in the same page?

Comment: i'm just trying to upload others image and upload it to db, but i won't work.
actually, i only want use 1 id, in dropzone doc shows the way. but it only show image not save to db with different name and insert into different field. @IdentityUnkn0wn

Comment: wher have you called the function birthday_upload??

Comment: in the form action where i place dropzone @IdentityUnkn0wn

Comment: <form action="your-path-to-file-upload-function" class="dropzone"  id="my-awesome-dropzone"></form> . this is where you have to place it

Comment: why do i have to put id in form? actually i already had id for valadation for my form. @IdentityUnkn0wn

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want to upload multiple files. You can set the `maxfile` limit in the `DropZone Options`

When ever user tries to exceed the limit, the event `maxfilesexceeded` will be triggered and you can perform your validation right there.

```
    Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
            maxFiles: 2,
      init: function() {
    this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file){
        alert("No more files can be uploaded!");
    });
  }
    }
```

If this does not solve your problem, please provide the error messages if you are recieving any.